# Laravel pm system if in query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to build Laravel pm system. I've created pm sending system, now I'm trying to make notification badge, if user has unseen messages. In my table I have two column: **sender_id** and **receiver_id**

My query:

```
return Threads::where('sender_id', Auth::id())->orWhere('receiver_id', Auth::id())
        ->join('messages', function($join)
        {
            $join->on('message_threads.id', 'messages.thread_id');
            $join->on('message_threads.sender_id', '!=', 'messages.user_id')->whereNull('messages.read_at')
                 ->orOn('message_threads.receiver_id', '!=', 'messages.user_id')->whereNull('messages.read_at');
        })->get();
```

But this looks like is bugging. Because same notification is showing for both users, sender and receiver. I think I need if, but where and how can I place it?

```
if ( $thread->receiver_id == Auth::id() ) {
    'sender.id'
} else {
    'receiver.id'
}
```

.. Thanks in advance !

Comment: why checking for sender_id and receiver_id (with OR)? I think for unseen you need only to check for receiver_id

Comment: @Bostjan yep, but when receiver sends message for sender, sender has not any notifications about new messages. Sorry for bad English

Comment: Hi @DisplayName, can you please post the schema, only the related tables, thread & messages